# How can I overwrite default settings in Zurb Foundation using Yeoman?

Tags: zurb-foundation, gruntjs, yeoman

I've installed **Zurb Foundation** into my **Yeoman** project using `yeoman install foundation` then included it in my project by updating my Gruntfile.js using `require: 'zurb-foundation'`

The problem now arises when I try to edit my `app/styles/main.scss` file. I am unable to override the default Zurb foundation SASS variables.

I've tried to edit the `_settings.scss` file within `app/components` and also under `components` in the main directory - but to no avail.

Has anyone had any luck or have a solution to this dilemma?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer myself.

The key is to put an `!important` declaration after your override (basic CSS doh!), and place this override in your own main.scss or equivalent file:

```
$mainColour: red!important
```

and don't forget to add the require statement in your **Gruntfile.js**:

```
compass: {
  dist: {
    options: {
      require: 'zurb-foundation',// ADD THIS LINE
      css_dir: 'temp/styles',
      sass_dir: 'app/styles',
      images_dir: 'app/images',
      javascripts_dir: 'temp/scripts',
      force: true
    }
  }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using yeoman-foundation-generator from github? https://github.com/pchen/yeoman-foundation-generator

It is like using standalone SASS and Foundation. You have to put the folder from the git repo inside your NPM installation.

Comment: Yes I looked at that, but I don't really want to edit anything via github just yet. I'd prefer to find a solution to the current method.